# How to correctly use a tkinter error message box to wait until user input meets requirement?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter message boxes in a way so that if a user provides an invalid entry, an error message box appears and, after selecting "okay," they have the opportunity to provide a new entry. However, no subsequent calculations should take place until the entry is valid.

In this simple example, the user is asked to input a positive number, which is then doubled. In the first portion of the script, I've included code to ensure the user cannot enter letters or special symbols. Then I use an if-then to double my number if it is positive and produce an error message box if it isn't. Of course, there's nothing here as of yet that suspends the calculation until the input is valid. This is where I'm struggling.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, messagebox
import re

def validate(string):
    regex = re.compile(r"(\+|\-)?[0-9.]*$")
    result = regex.match(string)
    return (string == ""
        or (string.count('+') <= 1
            and string.count('-') <= 1
            and string.count('.')<=1
            and result is not None
            and result.group(0) != ""))

def on_validate(P):
    return validate(P)    

window = Tk()

window.title("My Window")
window.geometry('800x800')
window.configure(bg='lightgrey')


input_label=Label(window,bg='lightgray',text="Enter positive number:")
input_label.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10, pady=10)

# Get input and test for valid characters
entry = Entry(window, validate="key",width=20)
vcmd = (entry.register(on_validate), '%P')
entry.config(validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

output_label=Label(window,width=20)
output_label.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=10, pady=10)

def _compute():
    input=float(entry.get())
    if input<=0:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","Input must be positive!")

        # What can I do here to suspend the process until my input is valid?

    else:
        input=float(entry.get())

    output_label.configure(text=str(2*input))

compute_button = Button(master=window, text="Compute",bg='lightgray',command=_compute)
compute_button.grid(row=2, column=0,padx=10, pady=10)

def _quit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()

quit_button = Button(master=window, text="Quit", bg='lightgray',command=_quit)
quit_button.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't suspend the calculation - anything like that would lock up the GUI.  Just exit the function, and let the user click the button again when they've updated their entry.

Comment: Why do you allow `+` or `-` if you want only positive number?

Comment: Sorry about that. For my ultimate purposes + or - will be permitted. I just tried to produce a small example here.

Comment: ***`#  can I do here to suspend`***: Simple do `return` and the user have to click again.